# Show that total curvature of ellipse is $2\pi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

I'm trying to show that the total curvature $$K=\int_C\kappa\,ds$$ is equal to $2\pi$ over the ellipse $C$ with axes $a,b$ (and $\kappa$ is curvature).

I computed:

$$x(t)=(a\cos t,b\sin t,0) \\ v(t)=(-a\sin t,b\cos t,0) \\ a(t)=-(a\cos t,b\sin t,0) \\ v(t)\times a(t)=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k \\ -a\sin t&b\cos t&0 \\ -a\cos t&-b\sin t&0\end{vmatrix}=(0,0,ab) \\ ||v(t)\times a(t)||=ab \\ ||v(t)||^2=a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t \\ K=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{||v\times a||}{||v||^3}||v||\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ab}{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t}dt$$ and now I'm stuck.

Please stick to multivariable-calc level methods, I am not familiar with differential geometry.

Comment: You talk and ask about curvature, which is a term of differential geometry, so how come you're not familiar with it?!

Comment: @DonAntonio I've known about curvature since as early as calc I... and I think it's introduced in many calculus textbooks (just in the plane, mind).

Comment: I don't see the point not to use differential geometry. For this particular case, it is more elementary than performing the integral. If $\vec{t}(s) = (\cos\theta(s),\sin\theta(s))$, then $\kappa(s) = \left|\frac{d\theta(s)}{ds}\right|$. For an ellipse, $\frac{d\theta(s)}{ds}$ always has the same sign. So $\int \kappa(s) ds = \int \left|\frac{d\theta(s)}{ds} \right| ds =  \left|\int \frac{d\theta}{ds}\right| = \left| \int d\theta \right| = 2\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trig substitution:

$$\frac{ab}{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t}dt= \frac{ab}{a^2\tan^2t+b^2}d(\tan t)$$

Comment: So I get $${b\over a}\tan^{-1}\left({a\tan t\over b}\right) \Bigg|_0^{2\pi}$$ But doesn't that equal $0$?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Um, where are you getting that from? Via $u=\frac{a}{b}\tan t$ you should get $$2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{du}{u^2+1}=2\pi.$$

Comment: I didn't transform the boundary points. Is the anti-derivative correct though?

Comment: What are you taking the antiderivative of?

Comment: I wrote $$\frac{a/b}{\tan^2 t+(b/a)^2}d(tan)$$ which has anti-derivative [what I wrote in first comment] I think I'm having a brain fart here.... I'm obviously missing something - when $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$, $\tan t=0$, so $u=0$ right? ahhhhhhhh.....

Comment: I would write $\frac{du}{u^2+1}$ as I did for greater convenience. Its antiderivative is $\tan^{-1}u$.

Comment: Can you explain the bounds? I'll accept your answer and then look this over tomorrow, because apparently my brain isn't functioning at the moment.

Comment: The function $\tan t$ traces out all of $(-\infty,\infty)$ exactly once per interval $[0,\pi)$ and $[\pi,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying @Blue's answer, taking $[0,2\pi]=[0,\pi/2]\cup(\pi/2,3\pi/2]\cup(3\pi/2,2\pi]$ and regarding that: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow (2k+1)\pi/2}\tan(x)=\pm\infty\qquad (k=0,1)$$

then:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sec^2(t)}{a^2\tan^2(t)+b^2}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+1}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+1}+\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\arctan(u)\biggl.\biggr|_{0}^{\infty}+\arctan(u)\biggl.\biggr|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\arctan(u)\biggl.\biggr|_{-\infty}^{0}=\pi/2+\pi+\pi/2=2\pi$$.